# Why below C code fails while compilation

Tags: c

I have a C code ,which uses simple comma operators

```
main()
{
int a= 1,2,3;
printf("%d",a);
}
```

Now when i compile got an error while same program with little modification runs fine

```
main()
{
int a;
    a= 1,2,3;
    printf("%d",a);
}
```

Why is it so?

Comment: Second code does **NOT** compile. `..\main.c:7:5: error: expected ';' before 'printf'`

Comment: where is 3printf("%d",3); , I can see only printf("%d",a);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first case, the error is raised because the compiler is not able to differentiate if you pretend to declare several variables or assign several values.

```
int a= 1,2,3;
```

Did you mean `int a; a = 1, 2, 3`, or `int a = 1, int 2, int 3`? Compiler cannot tell from context (even if *2* or *3* are not legal variable names).

This ambiguity does not exist in the second case, hence no error (but warnings issued anyway).

PS: it's [`int main()`](http://c-faq.com/ansi/maindecl.html) not `void main()`.

Comment: and the statement `a= 1,2,3;` is like having

a =1;
2;
3;

and after executing the first statement, a is assigned 1,
the expressions `2` and `3` are evaluated but nothing changes...

Answer (score 0):

When using variable initialization form, the comma does not act as the same operator. It is a special short-hand form for declaring multiple variables on the same line and thus requires its own syntax.

Thus in the statement `int a = 1, 2, 3`, the comma is actually being interpreted differently than in the statement `a = 1, 2, 3`.

The former is a syntax error because it doesn't meet the multiple variable declaration form. The second is valid syntax, but as others have pointed out is rather pointless because the statements `2;` and `3;` while syntactically correct, do nothing.

See [this article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).